# Question about Event of UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I hava some UILabel in UITableViewCell. My purpose is to call a function when I touch the specific UILabel. Please give me the train of thought.
  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UILabel is a subclass of UIResponder. You can override the these following methods to handle touches.

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, But i found that the userInteractionEnabled property must be assigned to YES, and then it really worked.